# Is there any difference in meaning between "not bother to do something" and "not bother doing something"?

Tags: difference, gerunds, infinitives

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *not bother to do something* and *not bother doing something*? For example:

> The guy didn't even **bother to clean up** after himself.
>
> The guy didn't even **bother cleaning up** after himself.

Answer (score 1):

Both are strikingly similar. to-infinitive and -ing form are interchangeable here.

Strictly speaking, I'd always prefer to use "*to infinitive*" when I want to specify *the speaker's view or attitude* rather than *a general sense.*

Similar constructions taking both verb forms:

> I like to have the mornings to myself.

> I like having the mornings to myself.